# Identity map from lower-limit topology to the standard topology is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f\colon (\mathbb{R},\tau_2) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau_1)$ be defined
> as $f(x)=x, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Here, $\tau_2$ is the topology
> of the half open intervals and $\tau_1$ is the usual topology of
> $\mathbb{R}$ Prove that $f$ isn't a homeomorphism.

---

If $f$ isn't continuous, it can't be a homeomorphism,

I take an open interval of $\tau_1$, say $(a,b)$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R},  a<b$.

$f^{-1}=f \implies f^{-1}(a,b)=(a,b)$

but the interval $(a,b)$ isn't open in $\tau_2$ therefore $f$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Do you mean "homeomorphism"?

Comment: What's your reasoning for the claim that the interval $(a,b)$ is not open in $t_2$?

Comment: see here, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/859640/591889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ **is** actually continuous: $f^{-1}[(a,b)]=(a,b)=\bigcup_{q \in (a,b)}[q,b)$ so an open interval is $\tau_2$-open.

But $f$ is not open as $f[[a,b)]=[a,b)$ is not open for $\tau_1$ as $a$ is not an interior point.

Comment: Why you use the fact $f$ in not open, I don't see how  it's related (maybe with some theorem idk ),  but the fact  $f[[a,b)]=[a,b)$  tell us $f^{-1}$ isn't continuous, and we can conclude

Comment: A function is a homeomorphism iff it is bijective, continuous and open (or equivalently in this case, closed). @lupusnox It does come down to $f^{-1}$ being continuous in the end, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The function takes a non-open set (a half-open interval in the usual topology) to an open set (a half-open interval in the half-open topology).  So, the preimage of an open set is not necessarily open, and the function is discontinuous.